# Android access main activity variables from another class

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a main activity class and find class. I need to access variable of main activity variable's that is "name" from find class. I tried to access with below snippet code but I get an error. How can I access main activity variables from another class ?

```
public class main extends Activity {

     public static String name=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                name=edittext.getText().toString();

            }
        });                                                
}
```

My second class....

```
public class find {

public void finder(){

    main mainactivity=new main();
    String incoming_name =mainactivity.name;//I can not use like that ? 
            // do something 
}
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) You shouldn't instantiate an activity, intents start activities

2) You have declared the variable `public static`, so you can simply reference it (without instantiating the class) by `main.name`...

Comment: what if I don't want it to be public ? how can I get it ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales OOPS basic concept says cannot access class and its contents unless the access modifier is public!

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to access `Activity`'s variables directly from another (outer) class. This is a bad practice, as Activities are, after all, part of the UI, and not the backend of the application.

Also, note that in your example, the `name` property is `static` and doesn;t belong to a specific instance.

Comment: So, how can I get the value of  edittext in this case ?

Comment: This requires to know the relation between the classes and the purpose of finder.

Comment: @MByD My purpose is that I have a flag in my activity and I want to update it from fragment, after user goes through some processes. What is the proper way to update a variable in activity?